# NextFocusDown doesn't work with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, android-xml

I'm trying to focus on the next edit text after the user fills one in. The code works absolutely fine with `EditText` but when I apply it on `AutoCompleteTextView`, the Next button in the keyboard doesn't work. The cursor stays where it is.
This is the code I'm using:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="11" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/etLN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etC"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/etC"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="0.0"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etD"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/etD"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etLN2"
        android:hint="0.0"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me what's the correct way to do this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

add this to your AutoCompleteTextView

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

and it should work.

Comment: if i could i would give you a bounty.. not that i have any(reputation).. still... thanks a lot @techieWings

Comment: I spend 5 days without figuring this out. Thanks heap.

Comment: Thx so much. saved me a lot of time.

Comment: nice one! Google should have fixed it by now